# How can one func connected to a signal reference multiple similar nodes? [godot]

Tags: scripting, game-engine, observer-pattern, godot

here is some code for the world node that I made to update some labels on what ability is collected and how many lives are left. The way the game works is that the enemies give you abilities when you collide with them and they are dead. The think is, using signals only lets me "contact" one node per function (as far as I'm aware). So how can I have the `_on_green_enemy_AbilityCollected` function correlate to every enemy that spawns/is in the game?

```
extends Node2D

var lives = 3
var ability = ""

onready var livesCounter = get_node("CanvasLayer/Lives")

onready var currentAbility = get_node("CanvasLayer/CurrentAbility")

func _on_player_minuslife():
    lives -= 1

func _on_green_enemy_AbilityCollected(node):
    ability = get_node(node).get("ability")

func _process(delta):
    var livestext = "LIVES LEFT: " + String(lives)
    livesCounter.text = livestext
    var Abilitytext = "CURRENT ABILITY: " + ability
    currentAbility.text = Abilitytext
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I circumvented this problem by instead of having the code on the enemy having it on the player, and using what move_and_collide returns to get the name of the ability variable from the node that collided with the player.